# iOS DNS falls back to cell network to work around filtering?

Tags: iphone, ios, network, dns, mobile-safari

I have my home wireless router configured to use Cloudlfare's 1.1.1.3 for DNS, which is intended to block malware and porn sites. With previous versions of iOS this seemed to work.  I've noticed that with newer iOS versions it no longer does, even if I place the device in airplane mode then re-enable WiFi, i.e. no traffic should be going out over the cell network.

Does this mean the device is sending DNS requests out over the cell network even though the phone is in airplane mode?  Or does it mean the phone is declining to resolve DNS requests using my local router, and is instead using some other DNS server unbeknownst to me?

Or is this some consequence of Apple adding DNS encryption?

I'm sanguine about the fact that anyone in my household who wants to access blocked sites can just disable WiFi and use the cell network (or manually configure a DNS server); at this point I'm mostly just curious from a technical standpoint about why/how the phone is behaving this way.